# chunksOf analog for ByteString?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I need to split bytestring into list of bytestrings diving first one by 100 characters. For lists, I can use `chunksOf` but not for `ByteString`.

Is there some proper way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `ByteString` and `Lazy.Bytestring` have [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:splitAt) [functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:splitAt) which you can use to [`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) a list.

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import Data.Int (Int64)

import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as Lazy

justWhen :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> Maybe b)
justWhen f g a = if f a then Just (g a) else Nothing

nothingWhen :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> Maybe b)
nothingWhen f = justWhen (not . f)

chunksOf :: Int -> BS.ByteString -> [BS.ByteString]
chunksOf x = unfoldr (nothingWhen BS.null (BS.splitAt x))

chunksOf' :: Int64 -> Lazy.ByteString -> [Lazy.ByteString]
chunksOf' x = unfoldr (nothingWhen Lazy.null (Lazy.splitAt x))
```

Building bytestrings for an example is easier with `OverloadedStrings`

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

main = do
    print $ chunksOf 3 ""
    print $ chunksOf 3 "Hello World!"
    print $ chunksOf' 3 ""
    print $ chunksOf' 3 "Hello, World"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for thorough description.